# filtrar fechas con dos DateTimePicker

Tags: delphi

hola estoy intentando filtrar fechas con dos DateTimePicker dándole click a un botón y el resultado aparezca en la grilla uso componente MYDAC y como base de datos MYSQL workbench 
este es mi código:

```
query.clear;
query.SQL.ADD('select * from compañia1 where fechavencimiento1 between'
       + ':FECHA_INI and :FECHA_FIN order by fechavencimiento1');
query.parambyname('FECHA_INI').AsDate := DateTimePicker1.date; 
query.parambyname('FECHA_FIN').AsDate := DateTimePicker2.date;
query.open;
```

Cuando intento compilar me da este error:

> "parametren 01-06-208 not found "

espero que me puedan ayudar gracias

Comment: Parece que el problema es cómo se están traduciendo los parámetros por parte de la librería (MyDAC) y según los TFormatSettings que tienes configurados. El código en sí, parece estar correcto.
Haz algunas pruebas para comprobar cómo te acepta las fechas MySQL (dd/mm/yyyy o mm/dd/yyyy,...) y en todo caso "monta" la sentencia SQL sin usar parámetros y formateando tú la fecha con la función FormatSettings.

Comment: Pablo, he realizado una edición a tu código, después de la de Germán. Veo sin embargo que el código original publicado no compilaría en Delphi (el SQL debe ser una cadena de texto, y el que tu publicas no lo es), por lo que el mensaje de error sería otro.  Recomiendo que publiques el código tal cual lo tienes en el proyecto, si no, puede que estemos dando vueltas al rededor de otro problema. Un saludo.